# Get OData Children Count with Filter option

Tags: odata, .net-6.0

I have created a OData service and Parent and Child relationship and I am looking for some help for the below case.

I need to retrieve all the data from Parent and Count of Children records and also want to check if the Children has Specific value. The below query works partially to some extent but it is not solving the purpose.

https://someURL/v1/Events?$expand=Attendees($select=userId;$count=true;$filter=(userid eq 1)

This query will give me the children count after filtering, but I am looking the overall children count for the Parent record.

Note: I don't want to pull all the records to client side and check UserId has 1 in this case.

Thanks,
Suresh